# Using canvas events

Tags: qgis, qgsmapcanvas

I'm trying to get the current coordinates from the `canvasClicked-event`. Browsing through various posts and documentation, I came up with the following code, but `handleCanvasClick` never gets hit.

What am I missing?

```py
def initGui(self):
    self.add_action(icon_path, text=self.tr(u'name'), callback=self.run, parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.pointTool.canvasClicked.connect( self.handleCanvasClick )
    self.first_start = True

def run(self):
    self.pointTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(self.iface.mapCanvas() )
    self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool( pointTool )

def handleCanvasClick( self ): 
    print( "test" )
```

Answer (score 3):

Move this statement within the `initGui(self)` function:

```py
self.pointTool.canvasClicked.connect(self.handleCanvasClick)
```